# How to prove that $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ is not injective?

Tags: functions

By looking at graph of $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$ I can clearly see that there are at least 2 points $x_1$, $x_2$ where: $$f(x_1) = f(x_2), \quad x_1 \neq x_2$$

How can I prove this function is not injective?

Problem here is that in contrast with function for example $f(x) = x^2$ you can check with negative $x$ to prove non injectivity, but in this case both $x_1$, $x_2$ are either positive or negative.

[image]

Comment: $f(\frac 1  x)=f(x)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks! But how do I find it for other function generally to prove injectivity/non injectivity? Is there any general approach or I have to "see it" somehow?

Comment: In your case, $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ reduces to $(x_1-x_2)(1-x_1x_2)$. But it's not so easy in general.

Comment: Just start with $f(x)=f(y)$ do some simple algebraic manipulation and you will come up with $y=\frac  1 x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start with $f(x)=f(y)$. Thus
$$yx^2-(1+y^2)x+y=0.$$
It's a second degree polynomial in $x$. You can easily see that $$\Delta = (y^2-1)^2.$$
So the two solutions for $x$ (if $y\neq 0$, otherwise the unique solution is $x=0$) are
$$\frac{1+y^2\pm (y^2-1)}{2y},$$
ie $x=y$ or $x=1/y$.

You can thus remark that the only points which have only one antecedent are $f(-1),f(0)$ and $f(1)$, ie $-1/2,0$ and $1/2$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x\ge 0;$

$f(x) =\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$, continuous.

$f(0)=0;$ $f(1)=1/2;$

$f(10)=\dfrac{10}{1+10^2}< 1/10$;

Intermediate Value Theorem for continuous functions

Consider the intervals $[0,1]$ and $[1,10].$

1)There is a $s \in [0,1]$ s.t. $f(s) = 1/4;$

2)There is a $r \in [1,10]$ $(r \not =1) $

s.t. $f(r)=1/4,$

and we are done.

Comment: A nice approach.  The correct spelling is continuous.

Comment: Taussig. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x=\tan(y), -\pi/2<y<\pi/2$, get $f(x)=g(y)=\tan(y)/(1/\cos^2(y))=1/2(\sin(2y))$. Then $\sqrt2/4=g(\pi/8)=g(3\pi/8)$. So $f(\tan(\pi/8))=f(\tan(3\pi/8))$.